# How to enable specific domains for app to open by default?

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, testing, adb

I am executing some tests on a debug build for an application and I have to test if some links redirect to the app in specific screens or configuration.

I've managed to set up the app as default to open links using:

```
adb shell pm set-app-links-allowed  --user 0 --package app.package.name true
```

But in some android versions (Android 12 and 13) this only sets the app as default to open supported links, but all of the 'Supported web addresses" are not enabled.

I've tried many alternatives, including:

```
adb shell pm set-app-links-allowed  --user 0 --domain  www.domainName.com --package app.package.name  true
```

But this does not seem to work.

Doing this manually would be:
Settings > Apps > App name > Set as default > Toggle on 'open supported links" > Supported web addresses > Enable desired domain/Enable all domains

Is there a way to perform this using adb shell?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "scheme://host"
```